# War Frame can't run because system shows 3.8 GIB memory although I have 4 GB

Tags: wine, games, steam, hardware, ram

I have 4 GB memory, but War Frame will not run because the system is showing 3.8 GIB memory which is supposedly not enough. Is there any way I can bypass RAM check and show system 4 GB memory?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581058/how-can-i-fake-the-amount-of-installed-ram-for-a-specific-program-in-linux

Comment: it doubles usage too any way to fake usage like ram ?